# Issue on Using One Switch Botton to Toggle Functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two buttons to slide up and down the page at [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/XpZBd/1/)  as:

```
<div id="map"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default green goinfo">Go Info</button></div>
<div id="info"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default green gomap">Go Map</button></div>
```

can you please let me know how I can reduce the buttons to do do the same job? something like :

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default slider">Switch View</button>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden'); 
     var viewheight = $('#map').height();


 $('.goinfo').fadeIn();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('.goinfo').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.goinfo').fadeOut();
        }
    });

     $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.gomap').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.gomap').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.gomap').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

     $('.goinfo').click(function () {

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: viewheight
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

    $( window ).resize(function() {
    var mapheight = $('#mapview').height();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the button outside both `div`s, below them.
2. Using CSS, style the button so it appears where you want (probably roughly `position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right; 10px;` but it is hard to say without knowing more about your page.
3. Put a local variable into your `ready` handler: `var down = false;`
4. In the button handler, do this:

Code:

```
if (down) {
   down = false;
   $('html, body').animate(...);
}
else {
   down = true;
   $('html, body').animate(...);
}
```

But honestly, I think what you have now is less complicated and not problematically wordy, so I wouldn't change it myself.